# Is there any way to find css in vue.js project?

Tags: vue.js, sass

```
<nav class="left-side">
```

this is my HTML tag. But on browse, I am getting

```
<nav v-d-asd0fd class="left-side">
```

can anybody tell from where does v-d-asd0fd generates? This same thing is also applied in CSS .plese help to find this

Answer (score 0):

When Webpack processes your project it's "Scoping" the CSS. Basically it means that each component's classes are unique to that component and can't fight with other classes. So you could have `left-side` in different components with different styles.

Vue CSS Scope [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html).

You can change it by removing the word scoped from your Style tag

`<style scoped>` to `<style>`